# Installing OpenConnect, Cisco VPN alternative

Tags: vpn

Has anyone had any luck installing [openconnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect.html) on OS X? I have downloaded the source code but I can't figure out how to build it.

The instructions on their website say to extract the code and run `make`, but doing so gives an error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

My reasons for wanting this are:

- The current version of Cisco AnyConnect is incompatible with OS X Lion
- I'm interested in the idea of wrapping the vpn connection in a deployment shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry; I forgot to update the web page when I switched to autoconf. I'll fix it.

Run ./configure and *then* make.

Why didn't you ask this on the mailing list though; I only happened to come across this question by pure chance.

It always confuses me when users ask questions about my software on random web fora instead of sending questions to me or the mailing list I specifically set up for them to use... :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now I'm working through some zlib and tuntap issues. Will see how far I get. Do you have any idea as to why zlib would not be found?

Comment: As for mailing lists, I guess those of us who have never used a mailing list find these types of forums a little more approachable. I'll try the mailing list next time though!

Comment: Nevermind about zlib, got it installed.

Answer (score 1):

OpenConnect is an SSL VPN client initially created to support AnyConnect SSL VPN from Cisco. Since then, it has been ported to support the Juniper SSL VPN which is now known as Pulse Connect Secure. [400-101 Dumps](http://www.exams4help.com/400-101-pdf-dumps.html)

OpenConnect is published under the GNU Lesser Public License, version 2.1.

Like vpnc, OpenConnect is not officially supported by Cisco Systems, Juniper Networks or Pulse Secure, nor is it associated in any way with them. Only happens to interoperate with your team.